How do I pass no arguments to GNU Parallel?
How do I pass no arguments to GNU Parallel? Basically, I'd like to loop a command:
parallel --dry-run command_to_repeat ::: `seq 100`

passes the arguments:
command_to_repeat 1
command_to_repeat 2
command_to_repeat 3
command_to_repeat 4
command_to_repeat 5
command_to_repeat 6
command_to_repeat 7
command_to_repeat 8
command_to_repeat 9
command_to_repeat 10
…

But I'd like:
command_to_repeat
command_to_repeat
command_to_repeat
command_to_repeat
command_to_repeat
command_to_repeat
command_to_repeat
command_to_repeat
command_to_repeat
command_to_repeat
…


https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_examples.html#example-run-the-same-command-10-times

From the docs, § "EXAMPLE: Run the same command 10 times":

If you want to run the same command with the same arguments 10 times in parallel you can do:
seq 10 | parallel -n0 my_command my_args


-tip: Dan Getz
From the manpage:

   -n max-args
       Use at most max-args arguments per command line.


